# ¿Por qué se cae el programa luego de hace correctamente la consulta a sap?

Tags: c#, sap

La semana pasada me indicaron que si había la posibilidad de crear aplicaciones externas en c# que consuman la data de sap b1 y esto es lo que he desarrollado y funciona:

```
private void btnver_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SAPbobsCOM.Company oCompany = new SAPbobsCOM.Company();
            try
            {

                oCompany.DbServerType = SAPbobsCOM.BoDataServerTypes.dst_MSSQL2005;
                oCompany.DbUserName = "sa";
                oCompany.DbPassword = "abcd1234";
                oCompany.Server = "180.168.1.5";
                oCompany.CompanyDB = (cmbSociedad.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString();
                oCompany.UserName = txtUsuario.Text;
                oCompany.Password = txtPassword.Text;
                oCompany.UseTrusted = false;
                oCompany.language = SAPbobsCOM.BoSuppLangs.ln_Spanish;

                int ret = oCompany.Connect();

                string errMsg = oCompany.GetLastErrorDescription();

                int ErrNo = oCompany.GetLastErrorCode();

                if (ErrNo != 0)
                {
                    oCompany.Disconnect();
                    lblResultado.Text = errMsg;
                }
                else
                {

                    Payments _pay = (Payments)oCompany.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.oIncomingPayments);
                    Recordset _oRecordSet = (Recordset)oCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset);
                    _oRecordSet.DoQuery("select * from [PGN_PROD].[dbo].[ORCT] Where DocDate = '19/06/2018' order by DocDate desc");

                    int cantidad = _oRecordSet.RecordCount;

                    string docnum = _oRecordSet.Fields.Item("DocNum").Value.ToString();
                    string canceled = _oRecordSet.Fields.Item("Canceled").Value.ToString();
                    string docdate = _oRecordSet.Fields.Item("DocDate").Value.ToString();
                    string resul = "1 - " + docnum + " - " + canceled + " - " + docdate + Environment.NewLine; ;


                    for (int i = 1; i < cantidad; i++)
                    {
                        _oRecordSet.MoveNext();
                        docnum = _oRecordSet.Fields.Item("DocNum").Value.ToString();
                        canceled = _oRecordSet.Fields.Item("Canceled").Value.ToString();
                        docdate = _oRecordSet.Fields.Item("DocDate").Value.ToString();

                        resul += (i + 1) + " - " + docnum + " - " + canceled + " - " + docdate + Environment.NewLine;

                    }

                    rtdocumentos.Text = resul;

                    lblResultado.Text = "Succes connected";

                    oCompany.Disconnect();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                oCompany.Disconnect();
                throw ex;

            }
        }
```

Y como dije ejecuta correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero luego se cae la aplicación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad no se que es lo que pasa o porque se cae la aplicación.
Si hace faltan datos no duden en preguntar.
Ojala me puedan ayudar.

Comment: ¿Se puede ver el detalle de la excepción?

Comment: Ese es el caso.. no entra en ninguna excepción me muestra directamente ese mensaje

Comment: sólo para probar, luego de esta línea: `_oRecordSet.DoQuery("select * from [PGN_PROD].[dbo].[ORCT] Where DocDate = '19/06/2018' order by DocDate desc");`  coloca el `oCompany.Disconnect();` , es decir la mueves del final del `try` y ejecuta nuevamente. Quizás el problema sea la conexión de red, es SAP, ergo, asumo que hay una buena cantidad de usuarios conectados. Saludos

Comment: sigue pasando, pero empiezo a creer que solo es en mi pc, porque el ejecutable se lo pase a un compañero y lo ha ejecutado y no  se le cae, o es que algo me falta en configuración?

Comment: Has revisado el `Visor de eventos` de `Windows`? Puede que haya más información del error. Cuántos registros estás recuperando? Por descartar problemas de memoria.

Comment: Sabes si ` SAPbobsCOM.Company` es una clase que implementa `IDisposable`? Lo digo por usarla dentro de un  bloque `using {}`.

Comment: acabo de ver el visor de eventos pero no hay nada, y al parecer tampoco implementa el IDisposable, la documentación indica que la forma de soltar los recursos es igualar a null el objeto SAPbobsCom.Company.
Ayer puede capturar el error en un depurador aparte pero solo he podido un a vez pero me indicaba que no encontraba el archivo wntdll.pdb.dll y que buscaba el ntdll.dll